# Unable to use lateinit variable in init

Tags: rust, embedded, bare-metal

I'm trying to make an embedded app with Rust and RTIC, that would talk over SPI and blink the LED, but I'm getting stuck at trying to share the GPIO bank over the `init` and `interrupt` functions.

In the `init` I have to set the SPI up using the GPIO bank, but I'm unable to set pins without using up the bank.

My code:

```
#![no_main]
#![no_std]

#[allow(unused_extern_crates)]
use panic_halt as _;

use asm_delay::AsmDelay;
use cortex_m_semihosting::hprint;
use hal::gpio::Level;
use hal::pac::interrupt;
use nrf52810_hal as hal;
use nrf52810_hal::prelude::*;
use nrf52810_pac as nrf;
use nrf52810_pac::{Interrupt, NVIC};

#[rtic::app(device = nrf52810_pac, peripherals = true)]
const APP: () = {
    struct Resources {
        LED: nrf52810_pac::p0::out::PIN20_W<'static>,
    }
    
    #[init]
    fn init(_: init::Context) -> init::LateResources {
        let p = hal::pac::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
        let LED = None;
        p.P0.out.write(|w| {LED = Some(*w.pin20()); w.pin20().low()});
        let li = init::LateResources{
            LED: LED.unwrap(),
        };
        let port0 = hal::gpio::p0::Parts::new(p.P0);
        let spiclk = port0.p0_25.into_push_pull_output(Level::Low).degrade();
        let spimosi = port0.p0_24.into_push_pull_output(Level::Low).degrade();
        let spimiso = port0.p0_23.into_floating_input().degrade();
        let pins = hal::spim::Pins {
            sck: spiclk,
            miso: Some(spimiso),
            mosi: Some(spimosi),
        };
        let spi = hal::Spim::new(
            p.SPIM0,
            pins,
            hal::spim::Frequency::K500,
            hal::spim::MODE_0,
            0,
        );

        let reference_data = "Hello World!".as_bytes();
        let mut eh_spi = embedded_hal_spy::new(spi, |_| {});
        use embedded_hal::blocking::spi::Write;
        match eh_spi.write(reference_data) {
            Ok(_) => {}
            Err(_) => {}
        }
        let mut d = AsmDelay::new(asm_delay::bitrate::U32BitrateExt::mhz(74));

        rtic::pend(Interrupt::SWI0_EGU0);
        li
    }

    #[task(binds = SWI0_EGU0, resources = [LED])]
    fn led_switch(_: led_switch::Context) {
        static mut LED_STATE: bool = false;
        // flip_led(LED_STATE);
        *LED_STATE = !*LED_STATE;
    }
};
```

## EDIT

I've managed to store the pin in the static variable that can be shared between functions, but I'm not sure how to toggle it's state, as it's, once again, required as a value and not a reference.

```
    struct Resources {
        LED: nrf52810_hal::gpio::p0::P0_20<Output<PushPull>>,
    }
    
    #[init]
    fn init(_: init::Context) -> init::LateResources {
        let p = hal::pac::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
        let port0 = hal::gpio::p0::Parts::new(p.P0);
        let spiclk = port0.p0_25.into_push_pull_output(Level::Low).degrade();
        let spimosi = port0.p0_24.into_push_pull_output(Level::Low).degrade();
        let spimiso = port0.p0_23.into_floating_input().degrade();
        let LED = port0.p0_20.into_push_pull_output(Level::High);
        let li = init::LateResources{
            LED,
        };
        let pins = hal::spim::Pins {
            sck: spiclk,
            miso: Some(spimiso),
            mosi: Some(spimosi),
        };
        let spi = hal::Spim::new(
            p.SPIM0,
            pins,
            hal::spim::Frequency::K500,
            hal::spim::MODE_0,
            0,
        );

        let reference_data = "Hello World!".as_bytes();
        let mut eh_spi = embedded_hal_spy::new(spi, |_| {});
        use embedded_hal::blocking::spi::Write;
        match eh_spi.write(reference_data) {
            Ok(_) => {}
            Err(_) => {}
        }
        rtic::pend(Interrupt::SWI0_EGU0);
        li
    }

    #[task(binds = SWI0_EGU0, resources = [LED])]
    fn led_switch(c: led_switch::Context) {
        static mut LED_STATE: bool = false;
        // flip_led(LED_STATE);
        let LED: &mut nrf52810_hal::gpio::p0::P0_20<Output<PushPull>> = c.resources.LED;
        if *LED_STATE {
            LED.into_push_pull_output(Level::Low);
        }else{
            LED.into_push_pull_output(Level::High);
        }
        *LED_STATE = !*LED_STATE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the code in the question by calling methods that can take a reference to change the state in the `led_switch`.

```
fn led_switch(cx: led_switch::Context) {
    static mut LED_STATE: bool = true;
    let led = cx.resources.led;
    if *LED_STATE {
        led.set_low().unwrap();
    }else{
        led.set_high().unwrap();
    }
    *LED_STATE = !*LED_STATE;
}
```